# How to reset a session in a sql connection pool?

Tags: java, sql, postgresql, jdbc, connection-pooling

i have a connection pool using `javax.sql.DataSource` and PostgreSQL JDBC. The process is simple, I'm taking a virtual connection from connection pool, process it, then close the virtual connection (release the connection to connection pool). Everything works fine.

But when I get the same virtual connection second time the session have the same data from the previous execution. Mainly temp tables that created in the previous execution. How can I reset the session after each execution? Or can you suggest any work around to solve the issue without using creating temp table if not exists query syntax.

sample code

```
   import java.sql.Connection;
   import javax.naming.Context;
   import javax.naming.InitialContext;
   import javax.naming.NamingException;
   import javax.sql.DataSource;
    
    public class Base {
    
 
      public  Connection getConnection() {
        Context ctx = (Context) new InitialContext().lookup("java:/comp/env");
         DataSource ds = (DataSource) ctx.lookup("database");
        Connection con = ds.getConnection();
        return con;
      }

       public Connection closeConnection( Connection con){
         if (con != null || !con.isClosed()) {
                con.close();
            }
   

    }
```

context.xml =>

```
   <Resource 
          accessToUnderlyingConnectionAllowed="true" 
        auth="Container" 
        closeMethod="close" 
        driverClassName="org.postgresql.Driver" 
        maxTotal="50"
        maxWaitMillis="60000" 
        removeAbandonedOnBorrow="true"
        maxIdle="20" 
        name="Database" 
        password="p*******" 
        type="javax.sql.DataSource" 
        url="jdbc:postgresql://dbUrl/dbName" 
        username="dbUser" 
        validationQuery="select version();"
       validationQueryTimeout="60"
    />
```

// use case

```
con = getconnection()
CallableStatement st = con.prepareCall("{ doSomething()}");
st.execute()
//processing
st.close()
con.close()
```

in doSomething() plpgsql function i have a temp table  creation (with name t_table), data processing and an array output. when i repeatedly call this from java first execution is success. But from the second execution  message saying that t_table already exist is thrown. I thought that when using connection pool, the connections in the pool are session independent IE. every new connections from pool will have a new session. PostgreSQL solution is to drop that particular temp table . But there is no other solution for this from the tomcat side ?

Comment: @ a_horse_with_no_name i have a function that  creates a temp table also there is an inner function with a commit. then the table will be dropped . so i am looking for a solution in the JDBC side itself

Comment: Then you need some code that drops the temp tables manually. Or get rid of them completely. More often than not, their usage isn't really required.

Comment: @ a_horse_with_no_name No other solution to handle it in the JDBC Side . i mean java side

Comment: Please provide a [mre] and specify which connection pool library you're using. Also, if you use global temporary tables, then you don't need to drop those tables: the definition can remain and be available for reuse.

Comment: That doesn't answer the question. `javax.sql.DataSource` is an interface, you are using a specific implementation, which is it? Tomcat built-in, Apache DBCP, HikariCP, etc?

Comment: tomcat built-in @Mark Rotteveel

Comment: @MarkRotteveel there are no global temporary tables in postgres.

Comment: @Jeremy PostgreSQL has global temporary tables, see https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-createtable.html Ah, never mind, I see it only provides GLOBAL for syntax compatibility.

Comment: In any case, that would suggest that the OP doesn't commit the transaction, and neither does the connection pool on returning the connection to the pool.

Comment: @MarkRotteveel the transaction is committed. the insert operation on the tables is a success. And i can query the contents of the table after the operation

Comment: @Jeremy in my use case, i have only local temporary tables. and i use it inside plPgSQL function for processing of data.

Comment: @MarkRotteveel is the temp table issue is normal or is it a problem in my configuration ?. i have edited the question to have some more clarification about my config.

Comment: I don't normally use temp tables, but the code you show is not a [mre], we need to see code that reproduces the problem in as few lines as possible, but still be representative of what your actual code is doing.

Comment: @MarkRotteveel ACcording to your request i updated my question. Anything more you want to know?

Comment: @SHARONXAVIER I think what people are trying to figure out is why you think you need temporary tables at all.  It's often, but not always, possible to avoid their use.  Temp tables can be useful, but they can lead to issues like you are seeing if a session tries to use the same table more than once.  If they are overused, they can also lead to a lot of churn in the catalog tables.

Comment: Thank you @Jeremy for your advice. Actually my app give preference for faster response time that's why i am using temp tables.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [`discard temporary`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-discard.html) command can be used to clean up a session.
You can configure that as a validation query to be run when the connection is *returned* to the pool.

With the Tomcat JDBC pool, this would be something like this:

```
validationQuery="discard temporary"
testWhileIdle="false"
testOnBorrow="false"
testOnReturn="true"
```

If you want to clean up the session even more, you can consider using `discard all` instead, but that requires autocommit to be enabled, not sure if that would work for you.

If such a statement isn't allowed, you can wrap it into a function:

```
create function session_cleanup()
  returns boolean
as
$$
  discard temporary;
  select true;
$$
language sql;
```

```
validationQuery="select session_cleanup()"
testWhileIdle="false"
testOnBorrow="false"
testOnReturn="true"
```

Comment: error occurs. because discard temporary doesn't return anything java.sql.SQLException: Cannot create PoolableConnectionFactory (No results were returned by the query.)

Comment: The put that into a function and use a `select my_cleanup()` in the configuration.

Comment: i am looking for a solution in tomcat configuration itself `select my_cleanup()` may take time.

Comment: If you can't use `discard temporary` the function is your only choice. The overhead of calling the function is extremely small and will be overshadowed by the actual work to drop the tables.

Comment: my app uses REST API's ,so for every call to db i have to loose significant amount of time. At least  i have to sacrifice 20 ms for a single call. so if i have 1000 API requests, then that is going to be a bottle neck for my application

Comment: There is no way you can reset the session on the database server without a roundtrip (request) to the database server. The overhead of sending a request to the database is way higher than the really small overhead of calling a function. The majority of the time spent in that call will be caused by the `discard temporary`  command, not the calling of the function.